# Generating Enode on private ethereum blockchain?

Tags: bash, blockchain, ethereum, geth, clique

I am currently in the process of creating a private clique proof-of-authority blockchain using geth. I currently have a problem of starting the bootnode and generating the ip (enode).

I am currently receiving this:

```
$ bootnode -nodekey bootnode.key
INFO [11-14|11:40:58.441] New local node record                    seq=1 
id=9d38dd0ca358d52c ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

following this https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster I should be receiving something like this

```
I0216 09:53:08.076155 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, 
enode://890b6b5367ef6072455fedbd7a24ebac239d442b18c5ab9d26f58a34
9dad35ee5783a0dd543e4f454fed22db9772efe28a3ed6f21e75674ef6203e47803da682@[::]:30301
```

The readme does seem outdated and I cannot find anything else relating to this? Could someone link me something to explain this? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
bootnode -nodekeyhex [Your node key] -writeaddress
```

I am still not quite sure why this is

Comment: I know this is very old post, but if someone happens to come to here, check this anwer, explained in super detail about the enode https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28978/21968